# Task switching brings focus to wrong desktop with maximised windows

Tags: unity, compiz, window-manager

Using ubuntu 16.04, I'm facing an issue where I want to switch to another window, the window manager activates another desktop (space) then where the window resides.
I've seen this issue on a couple of previous release.
It seemed to work better when it was still compiz.

Comment: Yep, I'm having the same issue right now, on Compiz+XFCE. Doesn't happen on my laptop though. Very strange.